# Update values & create new row - Google Sheets API

Tags: php, json, google-sheets-api

```
<?php 
$date_added = date('Y');
$api_key = 'abc';
$spreadsheet_id = '1-def';
$valueInputOption = 'USER_ENTERED';
$range="A9:F9";
$values = array("this","is","my","awesome","test","$date_added");
$access_token = "xyz";

$values_encoded = json_encode($values);

$AppendCellsRequest = "{
  'sheetId': 1,
  'rows': [
    {
      object(RowData)
    }
  ],
  'fields': $values_encoded,
}";

json_decode($AppendCellsRequest);

$url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'.$spreadsheet_id.'/values/'.$range.'?valueInputOption='.$valueInputOption.'?key='.$api_key.
        '?access_token='.$access_token.'?response_type=code';

$url_json = file_get_contents($url);

if(!$url_encoded = json_decode($url_json, true)) {
    echo "Sorry";
}

?>
```

My code is a little mucky but I'm pulling a blank at the moment.

Basically, I want my script to take in the values and add them into my google sheet.

For this example, I made the values just a simple array but I will include a very basic form for names, age & phone numbers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values), you can use the following methods:

- [`spreadsheets.values.update`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) to write data to a single range.

Try using this:

```
$values = array(
    array(
        // Cell values ...
    ),
    // Additional rows ...
);
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array(
  'values' => $values
));
$params = array(
  'valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption
);
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range,
    $body, $params);
```

- [`spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) to write multiple discontinuous ranges

Here's a sample that you can try:

```
$values = array(
    array(
        // Cell values ...
    ),
    // Additional rows ...
);
$data = array();
$data[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array(
  'range' => $range,
  'values' => $values
));
// Additional ranges to update ...

$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest(array(
  'valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption,
  'data' => $data
));
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
```

Additionally, you can choose if you want to overwrite existing data after a table or insert new rows for the new data. By default, the input overwrites data after the table. To write the new data into new rows, specify `insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $this->batchUpdateValues($id, 'A1:B2', 'USER_ENTERED', array(
        array('A', 'B'),
        array('C', 'D')
    ));
```

---

```
public function batchUpdateValues($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueInputOption,
  $_values)
{
    $service = $this->service;
    // [START sheets_batch_update_values]
    $values = [
        [
            // Cell values ...
        ],
        // Additional rows ...
    ];
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    $values = $_values;
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    $data = [];
    $data[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'range' => $range,
        'values' => $values
    ]);
    // Additional ranges to update ...
    $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
        'valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption,
        'data' => $data
    ]);
    $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
    printf("%d cells updated.", $result->getTotalUpdatedCells());
    // [END sheets_batch_update_values]
    return $result;
}
```

**Source:**

- https://github.com/googleworkspace/php-samples/blob/b00fd293c981b3ebacbd78de49015072614c0bd9/sheets/snippets/tests/SpreadsheetSnippetsTest.php
- https://github.com/googleworkspace/php-samples/blob/b00fd293c981b3ebacbd78de49015072614c0bd9/sheets/snippets/src/SpreadsheetSnippets.php